# Como alterar conteúdo de .htaccess via php?

Tags: php, htaccess

Queria saber se há algum jeito de se alterar o .htaccess via php.

Um exemplo do que desejo é que pelo htaccess posso restringir o acesso de um determinado ip com o comando:

```
deny from 67.114.135.60
```

Caso eu quisesse "desbloquear" o acesso de usuário via php(numa área administrativa por exemplo), sem ter que mexer no próprio arquivo, teria essa possibilidade via php?

Comment: `file_get_contents()` para ler o arquivo, `file_put_contents()` para escrever no arquivo

Comment: Sim, mas como poderia usar esses comandos para remover essa linha do comando deny? Com o file_put_contents() eu coloco conteúdo no arquivo, mas e para remover?

Comment: é apenas uma dica de onde poderá começar. Mãos a massa e boa sorte!

Comment: hehe, vou tentar sim, mas caso não consiga, voltarei aqui

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar esse, só trocando o "127.0." pelo IP inteiro ou por parte.

Lembre-se que se colocar parte do ip, irá bloquear todos os ip que começam com o número definido por você

```
<?php
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$deny_ip="127.0.";
if($ip==$deny_ip){
echo "acesso negado";
exit;
}
if(sizeof(explode($deny_ip,$ip))!=1){
echo "acesso negado";
exit;
}

echo "acesso permitido";
?>
```